# wait until jquery animation / slidedown has finished before starting new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I have the following nav menu [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cTd3V/4/)

I want to make each on mouseover event wait until the animation is contains is complete before starting a new one, which would start if a new menu item is hovered over (triggering the same mouseover event again).

I have tried using `.stop()` but this doesn't seam to be working.

If you hover between the sub titles (station / stop) really quickly you can see the colours dropping down really quickly.

JS

```
var parentList = $('.parent');

    // declare variables
    var currentChildTitle;
    var currentTitle;
    var banner;

    // setup append div function
    function dropBanner(currentTitle){
        // create the banner variable dom node
        banner = $('<div class="' + currentTitle + '"/></div>');
        // add it to the dom
        $('.boxes').append(banner);
        // animate it
        $('.' + currentTitle).stop().slideDown(300);
    }

    // setup a function to limit the number of divs appended
    function chop(){
        if ($('.boxes div').length > 15) {
            $('.boxes div').eq(0).remove();
        }
    }

    // listen for mouseover the parent list items
    parentList.on('mouseover', function(e) {

        if (!($(this).find('.locations-wrapper').is(':visible'))) {
            $(this).find('.locations-wrapper').stop().slideDown(300);
        };  

        // grab the current list item title
        currentTitle = $(this).find('a').attr('title');

        // call dropBanner passing the current list item title 
        dropBanner(currentTitle);
        chop();

    });

    // listen for mouseleave
    parentList.on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).find('.locations-wrapper').delay(300).slideUp(300);
        $('.boxes div').delay(300).slideUp(300);    
    });

    // listen for mouseover the submenu list items
    $('.sub-menu').on('mouseover', 'li', function(e){

        // grab the current list item title
        currentTitle = $(this).find('a').attr('title');

        // call dropBanner passing the current list item title 
        dropBanner(currentTitle);
        chop();

        // stop the bubbling up effect to parent list items
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

EDIT: Tried listening for the completion of the event with the following but still no luck..

Replace the dropBanner function with this. Helpful link http://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

New [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cTd3V/13/)

```
function dropBanner(currentTitle){
  // create the banner variable dom node
  banner = $('<div class="' + currentTitle + '"/></div>');
  // add it to the dom
  $('.boxes').append(banner);
  // $('.' + currentTitle).stop().slideDown(300);

  // animate it
  if ($('.boxes').find('div').last().hasClass('animated')) {        
    $('.' + currentTitle).slideDown(300);
  } else {
    $('.' + currentTitle).addClass('animated').slideDown(300, function(){
      $('.' + currentTitle).removeClass('animated').dequeue();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: you might want to listen to the event `complete` 
https://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: @jinyuan have added in code based on `complete` - still not stopping next animated though

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag:

```
var adding = false; // global

function dropDown(){
     adding = true;
     ....

     $('.' + currentTitle).stop().slideDown(300, function(){
         adding = false; // function called on completing animation
     });    
}
```

Then check in required events:

```
if(adding) return; // do nothing
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/cTd3V/5/) - might require to add more `if` constructs in the places you desire

Comment: Wait, **global** ? You sure that's the best choice of scope?

Comment: @Sukima I know it's not the best choice, but is there any other option. If the user is concerned about the scope, he can: 1. Complicate the name to `addingBanner` so as to avoid conflicts. 2. Wrap the whole thing inside a self-executing anonymous function. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/cTd3V/7/).

Comment: Um yes, IIFE is the better choice.

Comment: @GaurangTandon thanks - though I understand the concept I still can't manage to get it to work as desired...

Comment: @fidev I tried a lot, but the code is still a bit not easy to go through. What I can suggest: try the flag techinque. The places where to drop a new curtain place an `if` checking if the `adding` is already taking place (`true`). If yes, then don't do the animation, and if false, meaning no animation is currently taking place, do the current one. Set `adding` to `false` again once the current animation has finished (using the callbacks). Please try, I am trying my best to help :)